# Django can't access to manually-created S3 bucket folder

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using **django 1.7**, **python 2.7** and **django-storages** to manage amazon S3 files.

In my template I have an image link that displays the web-user avatar. My image model field it's default to something like 
"default/default.png".

Since Django hasn't any "collectmedia" in his core, I use the aws web console to create the folder and upload the file but it doesn't work. I get this error:

> Access Denied

I could imagine it's a permission/acount problem, like "you need to upload the file with the same django app aws account".

What is the best aproach to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

**"Are you trying to upload the avatar image from the web app you're writing with django?"** :
I am trying to figure out how to do that.

**"What do you mean django doesn't have any "collectmedia" in its core?"** :
Like manage.py collectstatic, which copy to S3 all statitc files in static_root.

**"Are you manually uploading the image file and you still get an "Access Denied" error?"** : Yes.

Comment: Could you clarify a few things in your question? Are you trying to upload the avatar image from the web app you're writing with django? What do you mean django doesn't have any "collectmedia" in its core? Are you manually uploading the image file and you still get an "Access Denied" error?

Comment: Have you given your bucket an access policy which allows operations on behalf of the AWS credentials you are using in django?

Answer (score 1):

If you storage backend is set to use S3 (django-storages comes to mind) then you do not need to create things manually at all. Please check your permissions and make sure the communication with AWS is setup correctly (bucket, privileges, keys)